# Merging variables by a group

Tags: r

I have a similar dataset to the one below, I would like to merge them based on the `"TA"`, the merged variable should look like `"ID1"€"ID2"`. The `TAs` are always in pairs

```r
usa <- data.frame(
  TA = c(111, 111, 121, 121, 131, 131, 141, 141),
  ID   = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B","C","D"))
```

The expected output is a new dataset

```
      TA     merged     
1    111     "A€B"  
2    121     "A€C"  
3    131     "A€B"     
4    141     "C€D"
```

Another option of an output

```
     TA     ID    merged
1    111    A     "A€B"
2    111    B     "A€B"
3    121    A     "A€C" 
4    121    C     "A€C" 
5    131    A     "A€B"
6    131    B     "A€B"
7    141    C     "C€D" 
8    141    D     "C€D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
usa %>% group_by(TA) %>% summarise(merged = str_c(ID, collapse = '\u20AC'))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     TA merged
  <dbl> <chr> 
1   111 A€B   
2   121 A€C   
3   131 A€B   
4   141 C€D
```

Second option:

```
usa %>% group_by(TA) %>% mutate(merged = str_c(ID, collapse = '\u20AC'))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   TA [4]
     TA ID    merged
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1   111 A     A€B   
2   111 B     A€B   
3   121 A     A€C   
4   121 C     A€C   
5   131 A     A€B   
6   131 B     A€B   
7   141 C     C€D   
8   141 D     C€D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` with `paste`:

```
aggregate(ID ~ TA, usa, paste, collapse = "\u20AC")
#   TA  ID
#1 111 A€B
#2 121 A€C
#3 131 A€B
#4 141 C€D
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(usa)[, .(ID = paste(ID, collapse='\u20AC')), TA]
```

-output

```
#    TA  ID
#1: 111 A€B
#2: 121 A€C
#3: 131 A€B
#4: 141 C€D
```